# regexp and strsplit use to separate string array then save the values in new array such

Tags: matlab

I have list of columns (more than 12200x3) contain string value called AffyID and I want to convert them to number and Symbol as you see in the table some AffyID have more than one number and Symbol separated by '///'

```
    AffyID           Gene Entrez           GeneSymbol   
       '53202_at'     '5683 /// 79020'       'C7orf25 /// PSMA2'
       '214878_at'    '100129482 /// 7587'   'ZNF37A /// ZNF37B'
       '200855_at'  '100131704 /// 149934 /// 9611' 'C20orf191 /// LOC100131704 /// NCOR1'
       '200856_x_at'    '100131704 /// 149934 /// 9611' 'C20orf191 /// LOC100131704 /// NCOR1'
        '200869_at'   '390354 /// 6142'    'RPL18A /// RPL18AP3'
```

I used strfind to separate Gene Entrez column then save the values in new  array such as

```
p1=strfind(EntrezList,'///');
   if(isempty(p1))
      j=j+1;
      filteredData(j,1)=raw_data(i,1);
      filteredData(j,2)=raw_data(i,2);
      filteredData(j,3)=raw_data(i,3);
   else
      j=j+1;
      entrez_ID=EntrezList(1:p1(1)-1);
      filteredData{j,1}= raw_data{i,1};
      filteredData{j,2}= str2double(entrez_ID);
      filteredData(j,3)= raw_data(i,3);
      if( length(p1)>1)
         for k=1:length(p1)-1
             j=j+1;
             entrez_ID=EntrezList(p1(k)+3:p1(k+1)-1);
             filteredData{j,1}= raw_data{i,1};
             filteredData{j,2}= str2double(entrez_ID);
             filteredData(j,3)= raw_data(i,3);
         end
```

Unfortunately I try to use regexp and strsplit to do the same with gene Symbols column but It doe not work

Could you help to sort out the problem I will be grateful to you
 I want the output like that:

```
    AffyID               Gene Entrez       GeneSymbol   
    '53202_at'       5683              C7orf25
    '53202_at'           79020             PSMA2   
    '214878_at'          100129482         ZNF37A
    '214878_at           7587              ZNF37B
```

Comment: Please excuse my comment if it offends you, but I'm having a difficult time with your language and understanding what is contained in your post.  I am not sure what your main objective is or what you want to accomplish.  Could you either edit your post to improve your grammar or show us a small example of the expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: If I've understood right, you want to pull apart a sting such as `s = '5683 /// 79020'` or even `s = '100 /// 200 /// 300'`? You can do this with `S = strsplit(s,'///')`.

Comment: You wont be able to use `str2double` on entries in `GeneSymbol`

Comment: Dear Steve, I want to save each symbol with the first column value in new array such as      214878_at        ZNF37A

Comment: Is the first bit of information you've provided the exact formatting that you're given? If not provide that because there are MUCH more efficient ways to do what you're trying to do without looping.

Comment: @Suever I have more than  12200x200 .... I could not put all o them in my posting

Comment: @James I realize that but if you can provide the first 10 lines copy/pasted from the file that would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regexp` is a life saver when it comes to such situations. I would suggest you try it out by reading about it from the documentation and trying expressions on regex101.com. In this case if you have the following variable in your workspace :

```
>> geneEntrez

geneEntrez = 

'5683 /// 79020'
'100129482 /// 7587'
'100131704 /// 149934 /// 9611'`
```

The following will give you:

```
geneEntrezSplit = regexp(geneEntrez,'(\d*)\D*','tokens')
geneEntrezSplit = 

{1x2 cell}
{1x2 cell}
{1x3 cell}
```

The new split cell array contains the string for each token. Finding the meaning of the regular expression is an exercise for you. For your gene symbols you would need the expression `(\w*)\W*`. Now if you have a Affy Id vaiables as:

```
>> geneAffyId

geneAffyId = 

'53202_at'
'214878_at'
'200855_at'
```

Combine these to produce a cell array using:

```
>> splitData = cellfun(@(x1,x2)[repmat({x1},length(x2),1) [x2{:}]'],geneAffyId,geneEntrezSplit,'UniformOutput',false)

splitData = 

{2x2 cell}
{2x2 cell}
{3x2 cell} 


>>tfmData = vertcat(splitData{:})

tfmData = 

'53202_at'     '5683'     
'53202_at'     '79020'    
'214878_at'    '100129482'
'214878_at'    '7587'     
'200855_at'    '100131704'
'200855_at'    '149934'   
'200855_at'    '9611'
```

I hope it gives you some idea how to get to your result. If you want to include the thiord column your cellfun call would like

```
splitData = cellfun(@(x1,x2,x3)[repmat({x1},length(x2),1) [x2{:}]' [x3{:}]'],geneAffyId,geneEntrezSplit,geneSymbolSplit'UniformOutput',false)
```